# Download image flashes open on load when it should be closed

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a button to show am image when clicked at the bottom of my website. I have included the code below. The issue is that the image flashes and is shown open when I load the page. How can I fix that issue?

```
<style>
/* -------- DOWNLOAD OUR APP -------- */
.byok-container {
    margin-left: 2rem;
    margin-right: 2rem;
    background-color: #22262b;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.byok-popup {
    display: none;
}
.popup-button {
    display: none;
}
.open-text {
    display: none;
}



/* Show popup */
.show-popup {
    display: grid;
}

.show-popup .byok-popup-content {
    transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
}

/* -------------- BREAKPOINTS -------------- */

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    /*.mobile-text {
    display: none;
}*/
.byok-popup-content {
        position: fixed;
        right: 40px;
        bottom: 13px;
        z-index: 30000;
        margin-top: 5px;
        background-color: #CFA240;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0.3rem;
        border-radius: 20px;
        transition: all 0.3s;
        transform: translateY(10%);
    }
.byok-open {
    background-color: #CFA240;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 10px;
    z-index: 100;
    border-radius: 40px;
}
    
.mobile-button {
    display: none;
}
    .byok-container {
        margin-left: 1rem;
        margin-right: 1rem;
        background-color: transparent;
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
        position: fixed;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .open-text {display: inline;}
    
    .byok-popup-container {
        overflow: scroll;
        transition: all 0.3s;
        z-index: 1000;
        background-color: transparent;
        width: 100%;
        height: 0%;
        display: block;
    }
    .popup-button {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #CFA240;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1rem 1.25rem;
    margin: 0.5rem;
    transition: 0.3s;
    text-align: left;
    border: none;
}
    .open-text {
    font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    margin: 0;
}
    .byok-popup-close {
    display: inline-flex;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.9rem;
    right: 1.5rem;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 500;
    line-height: 30px;
}

    .byok-popup-content {
        margin: auto;
        width: 300px;
        border-radius: 1.75rem;
    }
    .popup-img {
        width: 50px;
    }
    .byok-open {
        right: 40px;
    }
    .byok-close {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: #fff;
}
}
</style>
```

Here is the button and javascript:

```
<button class="popup-button byok-open" id="open-popup">
    <p class="open-text">DOWNLOAD OUR APP</p>
</button>

<div class="byok-popup byok-container" id="popup-container"> <!-- Main Container -->

        <div class="byok-popup-container"> <!-- Popup Container -->

        <div class="byok-popup-content"> <!-- Popup Content -->
            <div class="byok-popup-close" title="Close" id="byok-top-close">
                <div class="byok-close">×</div>
            </div>
            <img src="/img.php" alt="app QR code, scan to go to your app store">
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
const popupContainer = document.getElementById("popup-container");
const byokButton = document.getElementById("open-popup");
const popup = document.querySelector(".byok-popup");

// Open Popup
const showPopup = () => {
  sessionStorage.setItem('BYOK Activity', 'Active');
  popupContainer.classList.add('show-popup');
  byokButton.style.display = 'none';
  popup.style.display = 'grid';
  // Add close buttons
  const closeX = document.getElementById("byok-top-close");
  closeX.addEventListener('click', closePopup);
};

byokButton.addEventListener("click", showPopup);

// Close Popup
const closePopup = () => {
  sessionStorage.setItem('BYOK Activity', 'Inactive');
  popupContainer.classList.remove('show-popup');
    if (window.innerWidth >= 700){
  byokButton.style.display = "block";
    }
  popup.style.display = "none";
}

// Check browser width | Remove popup if mobile
const byokPopupActivity = () => {
  if ((window.innerWidth >= 700) && sessionStorage.getItem('BYOK Activity') === 'Active') {
    showPopup();
    return;
  } 
  closePopup();
  sessionStorage.setItem('BYOK Activity', 'Inactive');
}

byokPopupActivity();
</script>
```

Ive tried searching online for any similar issues but I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked fine for me and an image that I linked locally did not flash when loading the page. My recommendation if you are still having this issue is to set `display: none` for the image in your css and then set `display: block` on that image when you call the showPopup function. Hope this helps!

Comment: what would be the code for that?